# looking for software for converting audio -> midi

Tags: midi

I'd like to study grooves/midi notation from some old songs - any recommendations for audio to midi software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best audio -> midi software out there is definitely [Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/). You might find it a bit expensive, but it's a difficult task and it does a good job at it.